# Alpha users missing from Actions on Console

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

We've a Dialogflow Agent integrated with Actions on Google with Firebase Cloud Functions based fulfillment. The agent is deployed as Alpha release with a set of Alpha Test Users. We've been in the Alpha test mode for the last 3-4 months with about 10-20 users. Suddenly, in the past few days, the Alpha User list is not visible in the Actions on Google console. However, all the Alpha users are still able to access the agent as before. [image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been a temporary issue with Actions Console. It seems to have fixed itself.